# Is it safe to charge my Android phone very often?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, cellphone

I still have a S9 Galaxy phone, I always try to keep the battery higher than 80%. If it goes to 80% I go and charge it up to 100% then use it (normal use) until it reaches to 80% and start over the process.

Will this keep longer the battery? (Yes, I know I know lithium is designed to deeper discharges.) Another question, how do they consider a cycle? 100% to 0% is one cycle? As it would be 10 cycles of 100% to 90%?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. No safety issues.

Comment: `how do they consider a cycle?` ... who is `they`?

Comment: A cycle is a sequence of charge then discharge. [This "they"](https://www.powerelectronics.com/markets/mobile/article/21859861/proper-care-extends-liion-battery-life) says  "Using partial-discharge cycles can greatly increase cycle life, and charging to less than 100% capacity can increase battery life even further.". I don't buy it to the 100% capacity.

Comment: it's all safe, but if you want maximum battery life, it's best to have battery charged at around 60% (so instead of 80-100% you will get more lifetime from battery if you do 40%-60% cycles)

Answer (score 2):

There's not a safety problem with this.  However, too high or low a charge puts additional stress on the battery, and topping it off frequently burns it pretty quickly.  Keeping the battery level between 20% and 80% means you only get 60% of the power on a charge, but up to 5-10 times as many charge cycles.  (Of course, if I'm getting on a plane, I'll still charge it to 100%.)  It's probably safe to say that by keeping it over 80% all the time, you're doing more damage than letting it discharge most of the way before recharging.

https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries